# Azure SQL Pool / SSMS / error occurred during the pre-login handshake

Tags: sql-server, azure, handshake

Context: was connected to a SQL Server dedicated pool (azure) over SSMS. Running queries - everything going fine. Until I stopped a query mid-run and could no longer connect.

Error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.) (Framework Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider)

Utils:

Running zscaler on work machine.

Intersting:

Problem only exists when over ethernet connect. Can connect as expected over wifi. No one else has this issue connecting.

Blocks:

I need admin access to basically do anything on the machine.

Tried:
powershell `netsh winsock reset`
reseting: machine, router, zscaler, sql pool

Comment: I get this error _The specified network name is no longer available_ about 5% of the time that  Iconnect to Azure SQL and I simply reconnect. It seems to be an intermittent error.

Comment: @Nick.Mc yes others at my org told me the same thing! but this was not the case for me. It's solved but a mystery as to why it needed to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

My network admins made a specific zscaler rule for me and it allowed me to connect.